# Grails DetachedCriteria doesn't contain sqlRestriction

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I need to add subquery into `grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria`.

I tried to do this by another `grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria`, but in this case i found that `grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria` doesn't contain method `sqlRestriction()`.

Also i tried to add subquery by using `instance.add(Subqueries.exists(subquqery))` and hibernate `org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria`, this way works when i use `CriteriaBuilder`, but in `grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria`  it doesn't work because `grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria`doesn't contain `instance` variable.

Can anyone help me?

```
def result = DomainClass1.createCriteria().buildCriteria {
    //some other conditions...
    def subquery1 = DomainClass1.where {
        //some other conditions...
        def subquery2 = DomainClass2.where {
            projections {
                distinct 'id'
            }
            sqlRestriction 'timestamp < to_date(${date},'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')'
        }
        eqAll 'id', subquery2
    }
    eqAll 'id', subquery1
}.list()
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: When `sqlRestriction` is used, make sure you are referring to the actual table column names instead of the domain class property names.

Comment: @dmahapatro sure, but the problem is `grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria` doesn't contain this method and i don't know how i can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve what you want to without using `sqlRestriction`.

```
def result = DomainClass1.createCriteria().buildCriteria {
    //some other conditions...
    def subquery1 = DomainClass1.where {
        //some other conditions...
        def subquery2 = DomainClass2.where {
            //Assuming "timestamp" is the domain class property 
            //and not the column name and variable "date" is
            //a string formatted date with the format 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'
            timestamp.before(Date.parse('yyyyMMddHHmmss', date))
            projections {
                distinct 'id'
            }
            //sqlRestriction 'timestamp < to_date(${date},'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')'
        }
        eqAll 'id', subquery2
    }
    eqAll 'id', subquery1
}.list()
```